# How to get Set of keys or values from Set of Map.Entry in scala?

Tags: scala, collections, set

I have a set of Map.Entry like `Set<Map.Entry<String, ConfigValue>>` in scala. Now I want to get the Set either keys(String) or values(ConfigValue) in scala. Please suggest some easy solution for this problem.
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use `.map` to transform your `Set[Map.Entry[String,ConfigValue]]` to `Set[String]` and/or `Set[ConfigValue]`. however note that you might want to convert to `List` before to avoid collapsing duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

So if you have

```
val map: Set[Map[K, V]] = ???

val keys = map.flatMap(_.keySet) will give you Set[K]

val values = map.flatMap(_.values) will give you Set[V]
```

In both cases duplicates will be removed.

Comment: IIRC `Map.Entry[K,V]` is a single entry so it'd be kinda like scalas tuple `(K,V)`

Answer (score -1):

You could create a couple of functions that describe that computation, like:

```
val getKeys: Set[JavaMap.Entry[String, ConfigValue]] => Set[String] = _.map(_.getKey)
val getValues: Set[JavaMap.Entry[String, ConfigValue]] => Set[ConfigValue] = _.map(_.getValue)
```

Then when you need to extract one or the other you can call them like so:

```
val setOfKeyMap: Set[Map.Entry[String, ConfigValue]] = ???
...
val setOfKeys: Set[String] = getKeys(setOfKeyMap)
val setOfValues: Set[ConfigValue] = getValues(setOfKeyMap)
```